# NotSerializableException on anonymous class

Tags: java, serialization, hadoop, interface, anonymous-class

I have an interface for filtering items:

```
public interface KeyValFilter extends Serializable {
    public static final long serialVersionUID = 7069537470113689475L;
    public boolean acceptKey(String iKey, Iterable<String> iValues);
    public boolean acceptValue(String iKey, String value);
}
```

and a class containing a member of type `KeyValFilter`.

```
public class KeyValFilterCollector extends KeyValCollectorSkeleton {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3364382369044221888L;
    KeyValFilter filter;
    public KeyValFilterCollector(KeyValFilter filter) {
        this.filter=filter;
    }
}
```

When I try to initiate the `KeyValFilterCollector` with an anonymous class implementing `KeyValFilter`:

```
new KeyValFilterCollector(new KeyValFilter() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 7069537470113689475L;
        public boolean acceptKey(String iKey, Iterable<String> iValues) {
            for (String value : iValues) {
                if (value.startsWith("1:"))
                        return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        public boolean acceptValue(String iKey, String value) {
            return value.startsWith("0:");
        }
});
```

I get an exception: `Exception in thread "main" java.io.NotSerializableException`.

How do I make the anonymous class I wrote Serializable?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Joshua Bloch writes in his book [Effective Java, 2nd Edition](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/effectivejava-136174.html), Item 74:

> ***Inner classes* should not implement `Serializable`**. They use compiler-generated *synthetic* fields to store references to *enclosing instances* and to store values of local variables from enclosing scopes. How these fields correspond to the class definition is unspecified, as are the names of anonymous and local classes. Therefore, **the default serialized form of an inner class is illdefined**. A *static member class* can, however, implement `Serializable`.

Comment: I defined the member filter as static and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 11):

Usually, the problem seen when serializing anonymous class is that the enclosing class is not serializable (and the author failed to realize that serializing an anonymous class involves serializing its enclosing class).

An anonymous class is a *non-static inner class*. That means it has a hidden field which references an instance of the enclosing class. When you create it with `new KeyValFilter(){ ... }`, without explicit qualifying it (e.g. `something.new KeyValFilter(){ ... }`), then `this` is implicitly used as the instance of the enclosing class (as if you did `this.new KeyValFilter(){ ... }`). So when you serialize the anonymous class, that requires serializing all its fields, one of which is the instance of the enclosing class, which then must be serializable.

If you don't need to use any fields or methods of the enclosing class, you should use a static inner class instead. (It can't be anonymous or defined inside a method however.)

Comment: "and the author failed to realize that serializing an anonymous class involves serializing its enclosing class" . This was exactly my problem. Thanks for this hint.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare anonymous class serializable, but the class is only then really serializable, if all its fields are serializable.

See the example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Object myObj = new Serializable() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String str = "something";
        private Object ns = new Object(){};
    };
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
    oos.writeObject(myObj);
    oos.close();
    System.out.println("Success!");
}
```

If you comment the line

```
private Object ns = new Object(){};
```

The code finished with success, otherwise [`NotSerializableException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/NotSerializableException.html) is thrown.

Comment: This describes the general situation of all non-transient fields needing to be serializable on a class implementing `Serializable`, not specifically an anonymous class.