# Java 8: inline initialized hashmap not serializable

Tags: java, serialization, hashmap

Can somehow please help me understand this:

If I initialize a HashMap inline as follows:

```
Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<String, Object>(){{
                put("some-key", "some-value";
            }};
```

and I attempt to call some REST service, with this instance, it is not serialized correctly and service end point receives null.

If, however, I initialize the HashMap using regular mechanism:

```
 Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<>();
updates.put("some-key", "some-value");
```

This works just fine.  Values come across.  Anyone seen this?

Comment: Without much looking, suspect [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17804704/notserializableexception-on-anonymous-class) dupe.

Comment: Don't use the first way. It's a nasty hack.

Comment: The nested class implicitly contains a reference to your outer class which is probably not Serializable.

Comment: Guess have been spoiled by C#'s collection initializers.  Wish Java has something similar to make this language less verbose.