# parsing serialized interface object from activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, serialization, android-activity, interface

I have interface `Callback` class as shown below,

```
public interface Callback extends Serializable {
     void onResponse(int responseCode);
}
```

I use the above interface to parse as params callback object, like below

```
private Callback callback = new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(int responseCode) {
        switch (responseCode) {
            case ResponseCode.FACE_NOT_DETECT: {
                notifyText.setText("Face not detected");
                break;
            }
            case ResponseCode.FACE_TOO_FAR: {
                notifyText.setText("Face too far, Please get closer to the camera");
                break;
            }
            case ResponseCode.FACE_BLINK_TO_CAPTURE: {
                notifyText.setText("Blink once to capture your face image");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Then I use the above `callback` object to send to my library

```
FaceDetectFragment.newInstance(callback, mode);
```

In this `FaceDetectFragment` class, I manipulate the param as below,

```
 public static FaceDetectFragment newInstance(Callback callback, int mode) {
    if (faceInstance != null) {
        return faceInstance;
    }
    faceInstance = new FaceDetectFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable(KEY_USER_CALLBACK, callback);
    bundle.putInt(KEY_BIOMETRIC_MODE, mode);
    faceInstance.setArguments(bundle);

    return faceInstance;
}
```

Then I use above setted arguments in at `onCreate` method as shown below,

```
if (getArguments() != null) {
        clientCallback = (Callback) getArguments().getSerializable(KEY_USER_CALLBACK);
        biometricMode = getArguments().getInt(KEY_BIOMETRIC_MODE);
    }
```

Then in here I'll use callback object several times as below,

```
clientCallback.onResponse(ResponseCode.FACE_NOT_DETECT);
```

All the functionlaties are working fine, but when I paused the app, will throw an RuntimeException, the exception is shown as below,

```
 Process: com.ej.face_demo_android, PID: 29679
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.ej.face_demo_android.FaceDetectActivity$2)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1536)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1484)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:733)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1408)
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1133)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:773)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(FragmentState.java:124)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1316)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:639)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1505)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1411)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:733)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1408)
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1133)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:773)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:4146)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:4148)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
 Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.ej.face_demo_android.FaceDetectActivity
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1224)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1584)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1549)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1472)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1218)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1531)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1484) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:733) 
    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1408) 
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1133) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:773) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(FragmentState.java:124) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1316) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:639) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1505) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1411) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:733) 
    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1408) 
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1133) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:773) 
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:4146) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:4148) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

As my knowledge when I am pausing the app, the app trying to save the current state of the app, while saving the state, couldn't identify serialized call back to save in current state. What should I do to handle this exception?

**UPDATE**:
When we consider about the fragment life cycle, when `onPause` state is triggered, the current state wi saving in the stack, Then my serialize object will wrap into to the bundle again by `main thread`. This is the time error occurs as I analyzed

Thanks in advance for your valuable time!

Comment: I don't think you should serialize the callback. It doesn't make sense to me

Comment: Please provide us HOW and WHERE you call *FaceDetectFragment.newInstance()* showing us real parameters.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko without serializing object how can we send a value activity to fragment?
I think you probably know fragment constructor must have empty param.

Comment: you can use a setter for example. Or make your activity implement an interface, and then in fragment do `((YourInterface)getActivity()).yourMethod();`

Comment: Yeah, it's a good solution, Cause of above issue I moved to setter already, But I need to know what was the real issue.

Comment: You cannot serialize an interface. You can only serialize data. Why are you trying to put this `Callback` object in a `Bundle`? This makes no sense.

Comment: @DavidWasser, objects can serialize in java, so my interface callback object extended using serializable API. That's how we serialize the interface objects. No, we can serialize an object also. Why I put my callback function in Bundle, is when I getting new instance from my fragment I can initialze my callback when fragment object is creating.

Comment: You do understand that if you serialize and deserialize an object, you end up with 2 different instances. They aren't the same instance. Also, since your `Callback` doesn't have any data, what is it you are trying to achieve by serializing and deserializing this? It still makes no sense what you are trying to do

Comment: @DavidWasser, please look closely,  I've initialized the callback object. When we write an HTTP request using retrofit(as example), we can parse a callback object, that telling what will happen when a response comes. Something like that I am trying to do here mate.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, the "real problem" is that you are trying to serialize an instance of a class, not an interface. Your class is an anonymous inner class called `com.ej.face_demo_android.FaceDetectActivity$2` which you created here:

```
private Callback callback = new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(int responseCode) {
      switch (responseCode) {
        case ResponseCode.FACE_NOT_DETECT: {
            notifyText.setText("Face not detected");
            break;
        }
        case ResponseCode.FACE_TOO_FAR: {
            notifyText.setText("Face too far, Please get closer to the camera");
            break;
        }
        case ResponseCode.FACE_BLINK_TO_CAPTURE: {
            notifyText.setText("Blink once to capture your face image");
            break;
        }
      }
    }
};
```

It isn't possible to serialize this anonymous inner class. See [NotSerializableException on anonymous class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17804704/notserializableexception-on-anonymous-class) for more gory details.

If you really need to do this, create a real standalone class instead of an anonymous inner class. You might have more luck with that.

Comment: Does that mean interfaces are implementing as an inner class when we creating interface instance inside of a class?

Comment: If you create an anonymous class, then the anonymous class is implemented as an inner class, and contains a reference to the surrounding class. Also, there is no such thing as an **instance of an interface**. You can only create an **instance of a class**. In the code snippet above, you are creating an instance of an anonymous inner class that implements the interface `Callback`.

Comment: pretty good so far, Inner classes are encapsulated along with the main class. What if the anonymous class implements as static?